# phpbb3 and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, phpbb, phpbb3

i have a `wordpress` site and i am trying to add a `phpbb3` forum system

the two work great alone, i was able to setup the `WP phpBB Bridge` (im not sure if it works or what it is supose to do), but when i try to set up the `PHPBB Single Sign On` which (to my knowlage) should combine the wordpress & phpbb3` users i encounter some difficulties.

the path, auth and patches are "OK" but when i try to do the `common.php` step the site stops working.

this is what it says to do:

```
It seems that this file is the original common.php file.
you will have to rename this file from common.php to common-orig.php
the file is in the folder C:\wamp\www\sys\forum

This file must be copied from C:\wamp\www\sys\wp-content\plugins\phpbb-single-sign-on\files\common.php to C:\wamp\www\sys\forum/common.php
```

any ideas on what could be the problem?

thank you

Comment: did you try following the mentioned step and actually renaming the file?

Comment: yes i did and every time i do it or the setup does it the site in completely unresponsive and nothing shows no error or nothing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong and sure enough it was my stupidity.

i was trying to install 2 `wordpress phpbb3` bridges and they were messing each-other up.